# How to modify the placeholder color , without affecting the input text color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery code:-

```
if ($("#Choice").prop("checked"))
                    $("#Technology").attr("placeholder", "Search by Tag...").css({ "color": "#b2cde0" });
```

currently the placeholder will have the defined color, but also the input text will have the defined color. while i need to chnage the placeholder color, while keeping the default input text color ?

Answer (score 4):

Best way of doing this is to use `addClass()` to the element with the pre-defined placeholder vendor prefixed properties:

```
.someClass ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

.someClass :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

.someClass ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

.someClass :-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

You can use `addClass()` like so:

```
$( "#Technology" ).addClass( "someClass" );
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Similarly, if you need to remove the placeholder class when the `#Choice` is unchecked, you can use `removeClass()` to remove the CSS class above. [[http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/]](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/%5d)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how i will be assiging these classes inside my Jquery ?

Comment: i use the following $("#Technology").attr("placeholder", "Search by Tag...").addClass( "someClass" ); . but it did not work , neither the placeholder nor the text color was chnaged

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class which has placeholder color set to desired color. something like this:

**Css**

```
.pccolor::-webkit-input-placeholder,.pccolor:-moz-placeholder,.pccolor::-moz-placeholder,.pccolor:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color: #b2cde0;
 }
```

**Js**

```
 $("#Technology").addClass('pccolor');
```

Comment: this did not change the placeholder color

Comment: try alerting before this code. see if its getting triggered or not.

Answer (score 0):

To select just the placeholder you have to use some new selectors:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999;
    opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999;
    opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999;
}
```